# Android ListView OnItemClickListener Vs. View OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

Why does an OnClickListener for a View inside a ListView not respond to a trackball click on the view, while an OnItemClickListener for the ListView does respond to a trackball click on one of the ListView's views?

Comment: What is your use case for a ListView click event listener outside of list items?

Comment: I think i got the problem - as long as I have only an OnItemClickListener, without an OnClickListener for each view, than the OnItemClickListener responses to both touch and trackball events.

Thanks.

Comment: In theory if you wanted to "separate" the logic, you could also just use the OnItemClickListener to call OnClickListener, as well.  That way you could keep the "item click" logic in one method and the "general click" in the other.  It's not perfect, but it would essentially be like overriding the method and using a super call.

P.S.-Definitely did NOT look at the date on this thing when I posted.  Sorry!

Comment: It's not quite clear how your row layout looks like. If you rows doesn't have clickable view in it, when OnItemClickListener is called by design.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design.

The `ListView` component is specifically built to trigger those events in that way.  I believe they are actually defined in `AdapterView` abstract class.  Other `AdapterView` descendants (`Gallery`, `Spinner`, etc.) will also behave the same way.

There is also an `ONItemLongClick` as well.

`View.OnClick` is only used by controls with simple semantics, e.g. `Button` where there is only one "kind" of click.